# downloads of multiple urls whose link is stored in text file

Tags: netcdf

How to download all files (NETCDF files) using r-studio if I have multiple URLs stored in text documents.
Below is the few links stored in the text documents

https://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/session/39F9EF86-B091-11EA-A9C9-D6FA8C209DB0/0F244A4E-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197/0F287C04-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197///scrubbed.TRMM_3B42_Daily_7_precipitation.20190301.nc
https://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/session/39F9EF86-B091-11EA-A9C9-D6FA8C209DB0/0F244A4E-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197/0F287C04-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197///scrubbed.TRMM_3B42_Daily_7_precipitation.20190302.nc
https://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/session/39F9EF86-B091-11EA-A9C9-D6FA8C209DB0/0F244A4E-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197/0F287C04-0A0B-11EB-B795-C90803BCD197///scrubbed.TRMM_3B42_Daily_7_precipitation.20190303.nc

Comment: Please follow SO guidance when asking questions. You have not provided any evidence of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have user name and password. So you'll get **HTTP Basic: Access denied.**

If you need to download some links from .txt try to use jdownloader.